# Binary to Gray Code

Tags: digital-logic

I have built this 3-bit Binary to Gray Code circuit. I would like to know if it is correct.
I have used 2 Xor gates.

[image]

Comment: Not quite - the lsb (B0) doesn't go straight through its the msb that does. Label the circuit the other way so that B0 is where B2 is and G0 is where G2 is and its there.

Comment: I built the truth table wrong, nice catch.

Comment: no problem - your homework is complete

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. I'm studying, but nobody collects this for a grade nor assigns it. Thus, it is not homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circuit is ok but you have inverted the bits order. If you try to make the truth table of your circuit you can see that sometimes changes more than one bit at a time and so that it isn't Gray Code.
This is the circuit with the bits in the correct order:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFsN5W.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>